# Converting a kshell script to python

Tags: python

Can anyone guide me? I'm trying to migrate a kshell script to python.
If anyone could guide me on how to proceed on this task. Do I really need the function? I'm trying to make more concise easy to read. Thank you.
here is the code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
DB="BATCH_JOB_STAT"
LINE=$DB
export $DB
NoFile()
{
   # no file
   COLOR="clear"
   LINE=$DB" NO BATCH_JOB ERROR FLAG FOUND"
   echo $LINE
   $BB $BBDISP "status ${MACHINE}.BATCH_JOB_STAT $COLOR `date` $LINE"
   exit 1
}
MultiFile()
{
   fail_flag=0
   # Check more than One file
   files=$(ls /opt/rh/flag/*)
   for file in $files
   do
     if [ -f $file ] ; then
        ## echo "# Error. Flag File found: $file"
        fail_flag=1
     fi
   done
   ## echo "-- Fail flag is : $fail_flag"
   if [ $fail_flag -eq 0 ]; then
      # no FAIL status means GOOD
      COLOR="green"
      LINE=$DB" OK"
      echo $LINE
   else
      COLOR="red"
      LINE=$DB" BATCH_JOB ERROR FLAG FILE FOUND. <P> -- $file -- </P> <P> Support <A HREF=http://johndoe/support.htm> Tech </A>"
      echo $LINE
   fi
   $BB $BBDISP "status ${MACHINE}.BATCH_JOB_STAT $COLOR `date` $LINE"
}
# MAIN
file_count=$(ls -l /opt/rh/flag 2>/dev/null |grep -v total |wc -l)
case "$file_count" in
    0) NoFile ;;
    *) MultiFile ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: This is an open-ended question. A question in the form of "please give me tips on how to proceed" is not a good fit for the Q&A format of Stackoverflow, because there is no 'best' answer, and any answer is unlikely to help anyone else. Please try something, and ask a new question when you encounter a problem you cannot solve on your own. If you encounter such a problem, put the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I ofend you or anyone else. Is not my intention. I can only learn from my mistakes. This is my second post in 3 days of been a member. Thank you for your remarks

Comment: You have to try harder to offend me. ;-) I just leave a comment in the hopes someone will read it, and posts a better question the next time (or in some cases edits the question, which I don't think is really an option here). You can find some information in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to improve questions too. [This checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) for high-level operations on files in Python. And of course, [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) and [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) (which are used by the first).

Comment: Zulu, How would bee using shutil? I just trying to raise a flag if a file exists on that folder. Should I use "shutil.Error" could you please be more clear. I'm new to this game in Python. Thank you